# Adding dumb/presentational component on the navigation stack in React Native

Tags: react-native, design-patterns, navigation, react-navigation

tl;dr:
Is there a way to add a dumb/presentational React Native component on the `React Navigation` stack, so I don't leave the container when pressing the phones back button, but just show the previous component?

I cannot figure out how I should design my app. So far I have as many smart/container components as I have main pages (one for login, profile etc.) because my impression is that it is better to have few containers and more (presentaional) components.

So far I have only used top level navigation with React Navigation, but I have a flow where the user wants to book an appointment at the doctor.
My initial thought would be that I have one `BookingContainer` that renders different components, but I can't seem to figure a way to keep the navigation stack inside the one container, so now I have several containers (`BookingMainContainer`, `BookingChooseDateContainer` and `BookingChooseTimeSlotContainer`). The reason why I want one container is that much of the data I need is the same, so I want to just pass the data to the children instead of getting the (same) date from the state in the three related containers.